# Which is the better Subclass or handle logic?

Tags: c++, oop, logic, subclass

Let's say I have an edit box, It doesn't matter being on MFC or Win32 or...

I for some reason need to make the edit just accept the Alphabetical characters which means in the range "a z".

So I can subclass the edit with new proc and everything is fine.

But sometimes I use an edit with its default proc but I use some logic to handle the input for example:

```
bool isValid = true;
for(auto i(0); i != strlen(myEditBuffer); i++){
     if(!isalpha(myEditBuffer[i]){
          isValid = false;
          break;
     }
}
```

So above as you see I get the whole thing from the edit and use logic to decide whether it is valid or not input.

- The thing that matters me in this case: Which is the best Subclass or handle input using logic. I mean The performance, speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I mean The performance, speed.

At that point, you really might have been a victim of premature optimization. Unless you pinpoint the bottleneck of your application to be that for loop in your logic for example, then you are looking for efficiency gains in the wrong place.

It's all about *readability* and *maintenance*.

You should think about which approach would be better for the reader of your code (it could be you in the future!). Having a code with high readability really makes maintenance easier too, since the next person will easier understand what is going on.

> Which is the better Subclass or handle logic?

Your choice. Think what better suits your application and go for it.

For example, if the application uses a variety of editors (one for alphanumerical input, one for numerical input, one for accepting only letters, one for accepting only special characters, and so on), then it would make sense to have a class Editor and several subclasses alphanumericalEditor, numericEditor, and so on, where every subclass would inherit from Editor.